# Visual Studio 2008 network drive trust and .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, security, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 on a PC that also has .NET 4.0 installed to work on code that has to be kept on a network drive.

Question is, since .NET 4.0 overrides .NET 3.5 security settings, how the heck do I get VS2008 to trust the network drive?

Answer (score 0):

The 4.0 framework security settings do not override the 3.5 ones.  There are indepedent policies which are separately evaluated.  So to get 2008 to trust the drive after a 2010 install is no different than just simply getting a 2008 install to trust the network drive.  Here is a link that describes how to do that

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdc263t0(VS.80).aspx

Comment: The problem with these alleged "solutions" one finds on the Internet is that they ignore the presence of .NET 4.0. I cannot use these, because the tools they mention no longer exist, or are ineffective (caspol.exe).